# Sentinel Raven and the incapacitated condition (Is the warlock's raven clingy ?)

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, unearthed-arcana

As a warlock you can take the Raven Queen as your patron. The Sentinel Raven you get can do a lot of things but what caught my attention is the following :

> While perched on your shoulder, the raven can’t be targeted by any
>   attack or other harmful effect; only you can cast spells on it; it
>   can’t take damage; and it is incapacitated.

As long as the raven stays on the warlock's shoulder it is incapacitated. It is my understanding that being incapacitated prevents actions from being taken.

Which leaves me wondering, by RAW can the raven leave the warlock's shoulder willingly ?

Would the warlock have to push or throw the raven off their shoulders to end the incapacitated condition?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### The raven can leave of its own volition.

The full text of the incapacitated condition is (PHB 290):

> An incapacitated creature can’t take actions or reactions.

Being incapacitated does not forbid a creature from moving (though being stunned or unconscious does). Once the raven moves off of your shoulder, it is not longer incapacitated and can thus act normally.

Comment: So you're essentially trading safe harbor for no actions/reactions. Not a bad deal.